# PHP and MySQL with Morris chart

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I'm working with morris chart but do not know how to print two types oh Results with PHP and MySQL

I have this code that seems to work well showing the number of visits in graph but wanted to include the number of different users accessing in a day but do not know how to do.

```
$query = "
SELECT DATE(date) AS dt, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `acessos` GROUP BY DATE(date)
";
$result = mysql_query($query, $fb) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

$(function() {

```
Morris.Area({
    element: 'morris-area-chart',
    data: [
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
    {
        period: '<?php echo $row['dt']; ?>',
        acessos: '<?php echo $row['cnt']; ?>',
        user: '<?php echo $row['user']; ?>',
    },
    <?php } ?>],
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['acessos','user'],
    labels: ['acessos','user'],
    xLabels:['day'],
    pointSize: 2,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
});
```

});

Anyone have an idea? 
appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressing the number of different users.  You should update your code to use something other than the "mysql_" functions.

The function that you want is `count(distinct)`.  Assuming you have a `UserId` field, the query would look like:

```
SELECT DATE(date) AS dt, COUNT(*) AS cnt, COUNT(DISTINCT UserId) as NumUsers
FROM `acessos`
GROUP BY DATE(date)
ORDER BY DATE(date);
```

Note that I also included an explicit `order by`.  MySQL has deprecated the functionality that `group by` also does ordering.